# Pretty print a tree

Tags: java, tree, formatting, ascii-art

When you're working with trees one of the most useful methods to implement is a clear way to print them, the following is my solution to print a tree in Java:

```
class BlackRedBST{
    public static final NodeRB NILL = null;
    public static final boolean RED = true;
    public static final boolean BLACK = false;

    NodeRB root;

    public BlackRedBST () {
        root = NILL;
    }

    public void printTree(NodeRB tree, String indent, boolean print_leaf) {
        if(tree == NILL) {
            System.out.print((print_leaf?indent+"   |-+*\n":""));
        } else { 
            indent += "   ";
            if(tree.p == NILL || tree.p == null) {
                printTree(tree.right, indent + " ", print_leaf);
                System.out.print(indent + "+" + tree.value + "\n");
                printTree(tree.left, indent + " ", print_leaf);
            }else if(tree.p.right==tree) {
                printTree(tree.right, indent + " ", print_leaf);
                System.out.print(indent + "|+" + tree.value + "\n");
                printTree(tree.left, indent + "|", print_leaf);
            }
            else {  
                printTree(tree.right, indent + "|", print_leaf);
                System.out.print(indent + "|+" + tree.value + "\n");
                printTree(tree.left, indent + " ", print_leaf);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

To be clear in the following the NodeRB class:

```
class NodeRB{

    int value;
    NodeRB p;
    NodeRB left;
    NodeRB right;
    boolean color;
    int level;

    public NodeRB(int v) {
        value = v;
        color = BlackRedBST.RED;
        left = BlackRedBST.NILL;
        right = BlackRedBST.NILL;
        level = 1;
    }
}
```

To complete the code, here is a class with main to test my code:

```
public class PreattyPrintTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlackRedBST bst = new BlackRedBST();

        // this is a sample, but a method to add the nodes should be write
        bst.root = new NodeRB(1);

        bst.root.left = new NodeRB(2);
        bst.root.left.level = 2;
        bst.root.left.p=bst.root;
        bst.root.right = new NodeRB(3);
        bst.root.right.p = bst.root;
        bst.root.right.level = 2;

        bst.printTree(bst.root, "\t", true);
    }

}
```

An output sample, with three nodes and print of leaf enabled:

```
           |-+*
       |+3
       |   |-+*
   +1
       |   |-+*
       |+2
           |-+*
```

How can the printTree method be improved?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does this compile? What's `NILL`? Please always make sure that any code is working *as far as you know* before posting it here, otherwise it's considered off-topic. Also it wouldn't hurt to include a bit more context, perhaps the class definition for `NoteRB`, or even a full example so that reviewers can run it too.

Comment: I've updated the code with complete class. Thanks.

Comment: @DAme is this currently working? If so could you provide an example? I tried but to no success

Comment: @DAme `p` is never filled in. Could you provide an example of a tree to output?

Comment: @dustytrash the code is currently working, you have to write a main and create your tree, then print it.

Comment: @dfhwze the method that add a node to the tree is not provided, you should write it and fill p with parent node. I will provide a sample output asap.

Comment: Nicer would look `─┌└┡...` of the Unicode U+25xx range. In general I would expect the recursive call to give back the used size for the subtree. So the drawing is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

A view more suggestions with explanation to the current source code (first `BlackRedBST`).

I deleted `public static final NodeRB NILL = null;` because `null` can be used instead of `NILL` for less code.

I also deleted `public static final boolean RED = true;` and `public static final boolean BLACK = false;` because color is never used (in the given code).

There is no access modifier for `NodeRB root;`. Class members should be "as private as possible" to prevent direct modifications from outside (threads and so on) and created appropriate getter and setter methods.

There is a nested `if-else` tree. I always try to do as less `if-else` branches as possible with respect to a better readable sourcecode. I stop each if-branch with a `return;` to ensure correct code reaction.

The `tree.p == null` branch of `if(tree.p == NILL || tree.p == null)` was never covered so it is removed as well for less code and a smaller footprint. [1]

The `print_leaf` branch was never fully covered in the `if(tree.p == NILL || tree.p == null)` branch thus I removed `print_leaf` as well.

Then I refactored similar code to the `private void printLeaf(final NodeRB tree, final String indent, final String indentSuffix1, final String indentSuffix2, final String indentSuffix3)` method and applied it where necessary.

The constructor `public BlackRedBST()` does nothing special. Initializing `root = null;` doesn't matter. The constructor is removed.

Since colors aren't used its renamed to `BinarySearchTree`.

```
class BinarySearchTree {

    private Node root;

    public void printTree(final Node tree, String indent) {
        if (tree == null) {
            System.out.print(indent + " |-+*\n");
            return;
        }
        indent += " ";
        if (tree.getParentNode() == null) {
            printLeaf(tree, indent, " ", "+", " ");
            return;
        }
        if (tree.getParentNode().getRightNode() == tree) {
            printLeaf(tree, indent, " ", "|+", "|");
            return;
        }
        printLeaf(tree, indent, "|", "|+", " ");
    }

    private void printLeaf(final Node tree, final String indent, final String indentSuffix1, final String indentSuffix2, final String indentSuffix3) {
        printTree(tree.getRightNode(), indent + indentSuffix1);
        System.out.print(indent + indentSuffix2 + tree.getValue() + "\n");
        printTree(tree.getLeftNode(), indent + indentSuffix3);
    }

    public Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(final Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

}
```

The `NodeRB` class looks like a model class so i made each attribute `private` and used getter and setter methods for accessing the data.

Level isn't used therefore its removed.

Since colors aren't used its renamed to `Node`.

```
public class Node {

    private int value;
    private Node parentNode;
    private Node leftNode;
    private Node rightNode;

    public Node(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Node getParentNode() {
        return parentNode;
    }

    public void setParentNode(final Node parent) {
        parentNode = parent;
    }

    public Node getLeftNode() {
        return leftNode;
    }

    public void setLeftNode(final Node left) {
        leftNode = left;
    }

    public Node getRightNode() {
        return rightNode;
    }

    public void setRightNode(final Node right) {
        rightNode = right;
    }

}
```

The `PrettyPrintTree` class uses the constructors and the getter and setter methods of `Node` as intended.

```
public class PrettyPrintTree {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();

        // this is a sample, but a method to add the nodes should be writen
        bst.setRoot(new Node(1));

        final Node root = bst.getRoot();
        root.setLeftNode(new Node(2));

        final Node leftNode = root.getLeftNode();
        leftNode.setParentNode(root);
        root.setRightNode(new Node(3));

        final Node rightNode = root.getRightNode();
        rightNode.setParentNode(root);

        bst.printTree(root, "\t");
    }

}
```

---

[1] Codecoverage was used in the Eclipse IDE with the EclEmma plugin.